# How to make sense of this javascript code

Tags: javascript, decode

I have been trying to make sense of this code. My old developer redesigned my website couple of years ago. Recently, i stumbled upon this code while reviewing something. Trying to understand what this code is. I know its packed, what format or encoding are these "_0xc23ex1" variables in?

I have tried to decode, deminify, decompress already but to no avail. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
eval(function (_0xc23ex1,_0xc23ex2,_0xc23ex3,_0xc23ex4,_0xc23ex5,_0xc23ex6){_0xc23ex5=function (_0xc23ex3){return (_0xc23ex3<_0xc23ex2?_0x3da8[4]:_0xc23ex5(parseInt(_0xc23ex3/_0xc23ex2)))+((_0xc23ex3=_0xc23ex3%_0xc23ex2)>35?String[_0x3da8[5]](_0xc23ex3+29):_0xc23ex3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0x3da8[4][_0x3da8[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xc23ex3--){_0xc23ex6[_0xc23ex5(_0xc23ex3)]=_0xc23ex4[_0xc23ex3]||_0xc23ex5(_0xc23ex3);} ;_0xc23ex4=[function (_0xc23ex5){return _0xc23ex6[_0xc23ex5];} ];_0xc23ex5=function (){return _0x3da8[7];} ;_0xc23ex3=1;} ;while(_0xc23ex3--){if(_0xc23ex4[_0xc23ex3]){_0xc23ex1=_0xc23ex1[_0x3da8[6]]( new RegExp(_0x3da8[8]+_0xc23ex5(_0xc23ex3)+_0x3da8[8],_0x3da8[9]),_0xc23ex4[_0xc23ex3]);} ;} ;return _0xc23ex1;} (_0x3da8[0],62,668,_0x3da8[3][_0x3da8[2]](_0x3da8[1]),0,{}));
```

Also on the other hand, before this eval function there are few variable assignments like below(just a snippet of what i have).

```
var _0x3da8=["\x62\x3D\x5B\x27\x33\x44\x27\x2C\x27\x34\x58\x2D\x34"]
```

and i decoded them using [ddecode](http://www.ddecode.com) which decoded to this below code but i still cant make any sense of it. What else should i be doing? What am i missing?

```
var
_0x3da8=["b=['3D','4X-4A','||||','0','|||]','1','||]|','2','||]]','3','|]||','4','|]|]','5','|]]|','6','|]]]','7',']|||','8',']||]','9','3p','3p','','','1g://','','a9://','','2e.','','.','3p','','aI','3D','aw 9z 9C 9D - 9G 9F M <2z>','</2z> 9E 9x 9w 9q 9p M <2z>','</2z>. 9n 9r 9s 9u 9H: <5a><a s="1g://3j.3l.U/3k/3u/3v-3F-3E-3G-3H-3J.1x" 3f="3I">9I 9W</a></5a>','','',']"]
```

My First question here, guide me if i am doing something wrong w.r.t SO rules.

Comment: Welcome to SO. My first hunch is that you've been hacked. Is that code in a file that you recognize?

Comment: It looks like those "_0xc23ex1" are all variables. You would have to post all of those variable assignments for anyone to make sense of what the code does. It's not a good sign that the code is written this way though.

Comment: Yeah, we'll definitely need more code. It's obviously been obfuscated though - you didn't pay for this code did you?

Comment: Its part of the main template file, the JS code does have other variables like the social icons and other necessary attributes.

Comment: I paid for the web design and to develop the site for me but definitely not for this piece of code!

Comment: Sounds your dev has you over a barrel. Looks like he deliberately screwed up the code so you would have to hire him again to maintain the site.

Comment: The encoding in the variable assignments are called string literals btw. Each one of those "\x62" sequences translates to a single character as per this table: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex . So he's storing obfuscated lines of code into these weird variables and then using those weird variables to build a program.

Comment: `Syntax error at line 1: expected ')'`? Please post the whole script.

Comment: I hope the duplicate I found serves as a good pointer. If there's still something unclear, post a comment and I'll reopen (and possibly answer) the question.

Comment: Is it a template for blogger?

Comment: @bergi here is the full code http://pastebin.com/Xc5CY7Lx

Comment: @Dr.Molle yes, its a blogger template

Comment: I would guess this code will create some settings for the template. I've found similar code e.g. at http://bloggercando.blogspot.de/2014/05/easy-news-free-responsive-magazine-template.html

Comment: @Dr.Molle how can that be? is that some generic open source script which other developers can use?

Comment: This code is specific for the template. When you click on "get template code" in the linked page you will see that the code contains such a script.